# Using Vue component in a Laravel Mix project

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, components, laravel-mix

I created a laravel mix project with the following steps : https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/installation and installed vuejs.

My app.js looks like :

```
/* Libraries */
import Vue from 'vue';

/* Components */
import test from './components/test';

/* Initialize */
/* Render Vue.js instance on  #app div */
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components:{
        test,
    }
});
```

I have a components 'test' who contains :

```
<template>
    <div class="test-vue">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "test",
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'Hello World',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Actually it's a wordpress site so I import my script using wp_enqueue_scripts in my function.php

I tried to use my component in one of my '.php' file but nothing appears. Can I use a component globally in all of my php file ? Where do I have to import my app.js ?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Are you trying to import that js before building it? because that won't work. You will have to build the JS and import that with enqueue scripts. also `{{ Hello World }}` is incorrect. its `{{ message }}`

Comment: I'm using wp_enqueue_script, it looks like : `wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/app.js', NULL, NULL, TRUE);`

Comment: Just making sure, you have ran the command `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` to compile it down correct? as that won't run straight in the browser.

Comment: I finally found the error, I was enqueueing 2 of my script with the same handle name (my script.js and app.js) however the name of the script should be unique so only my first script was enqueuing and not my app.js. Thanks for your help :)!